# How to rebase and automatically resolve conflicts

Tags: git

Long story short I have a repo with >1000 commits. There is a string that I want to change near the beginning, so say 900 commits ago. The string then does not change through the rest of the 900 commits. So far so good. Using `git rebase --interactive '<commit>'` works just fine and I made the edit. However after hitting `git rebase --continue` I hit a merge conflict... in a file that is completely unrelated. As far as I understand that's because git is rewriting stuff, so when it reaches a point where there previously was a conflict it will force you to resolve this conflict anew. I don't remember what happened 850 commits ago, so I can't merge it now. Furthermore I don't want to merge every conflict that ever existed *again*.

I also tried `git config --global rerere.enabled 1`, but no luck - I think this just records the resolutions locally and I don't have them locally.

Is there a way to tell git to merge stuff the same way it was merged originally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way: don't do this.

If you *really* want to do this, don't use `git rebase`; use `git filter-branch` or its new replacement, `git filter-repo`.

Rebase works by *copying* commits.  The new commits are new, and therefore different; they therefore have different hash IDs.  The result is a new repository, not compatible with the original repository.

The same thing happens with filter-branch / filter-repo, which is why you should not do this even though these are much easier to get right than a massive rebase.

If you *really* want to do this, and really want to use rebase specifically, make sure you have the new `--rebase-merges` option and use that, otherwise rebase will "linearize" / "flatten" the history (the set of commits including branch-and-merge operations), and that will make a mess of things.

Comment: git filter-repo seems to be the thing I need - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't resolve any conflict automatically, otherwise it would't have been a conflict

You can use `-S ours` flag to do a Copy Merge 
**OR** 
You can use `-Xtheirs` flag to do use changes done on source branch